# Using PayPal API

Tags: api, paypal

Is it possible to view/update user profile information using PayPal API?
I am able to send/receive payments using PayPal RestAPI and also have a sample to see account balance. Now I have the above requirement. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything to edit an existing profile, no.  The closest to that would be creating brand new accounts through the API, which can be done using [Adaptive Accounts](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-accounts/integration-guide/ACIntroduction/).

Again, though, if you're just wanting to update an existing profile there is no API for that as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is an update merchant info api

```
PUT /v1/customer/partners/merchant-accounts/{merchant_payer_id}
```

Check https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/managed-accounts/#partner-merchant_update